# Compare the number of comparisons used by the insertion sort to sort the list $ 7, 4, 3, 8, 1, 5, 4, 2$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Compare the number of comparisons used by the insertion sort to sort the list $ 7, 4, 3, 8, 1, 5, 4, 2$? I found that based on the following pseudocode for the algorithm:

```
/* Function to sort an array using insertion sort*/
void insertionSort(int arr[], int n)  
{  
    int i, key, j;  
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) 
    {  
        key = arr[i];  
        j = i - 1;  
  
        /* Move elements of arr[0..i-1], that are  
        greater than key, to one position ahead  
        of their current position */
        while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > key) 
        {  
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];  
            j = j - 1;  
        }  
        arr[j + 1] = key;  
    }  
}
```

The total should be starting from phase 1 that begins with 4 and 7 is: $1+2+0+4+3+4+7$, but the correct answer should be $1+1+3+1+4+3+2=15$, can you please explain why we need 15?

My solution:

**Phase 1:** compare 4 with 7 needs 1. 
**Phase 2:** compare 3 with 7 with 3 with 4 needs 2.
**Phase 3:** compare 8 with 7 needs 1.
**Phase 4:** compare 1 with 8 with 7 with 4 with 3 needs 4.
...etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your answer $1+2+0+4+3+4+7$, I think that $0$ should be a $1$. Other than that, your answer looks good to me. It might be worthwhile to discuss with your instructor.

Comment: This is based on Kenneth book's solution manual indeed. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It sounds like maybe there is an error in his solutions manual, or he has a different convention as to what constitutes a comparison. I'm not overly familiar with what he does here, so I'm hesitant to speak about it.